# Change the order of iteration over vertex in Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-graph

I need to iterate graph vertices N times, where in each iteration I want a different order of appeareance of each vertex. I know how to do this by creating a vector of vertex descriptor:

```
...
VertexIter itG1=boost::vertices(g).first;
VertexIter itG1End=boost::vertices(g).second;

while(itG1!=itG1End)
    vID.push_back(*itG1)
    itG1++

for (i=0; i< N; i++){
    shuffle(vID.begin(),vID.end(),RNG)
    vector<vertexDesc>::iterator idIterator;
    idIterator idIT = vID.begin();
    idIterator idEND = vID.end();

    while(idIT!=idEND){

        do_something_with(*idIT);
        idIT++;

   }
}
```

I would like instead to achieve, something like this:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  boost::minstd_rand gen;
  struct Vertex{ int foo;};
  struct Edge{std::string blah;};

  typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge > Graph;
  typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
  typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;
  typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertexIter;
  typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edgeIter;

  Graph g;

  boost::generate_random_graph<Graph,boost::minstd_rand>(g, 10,20, gen);
std::shuffle(boost::vertices(g).first,boost::vertices(g).second,std::default_random_engine(time(NULL)));

  return 0;

}
```

But compiler complains about something with std::swap.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to change from having the vector-of-descriptors? That's definitely the more efficient way.

Even if you actually were able to swap vertices (which, you already found, you can't for adjacency lists), since the descriptors *are* the vertex id in this scenario, you would effectively merely shuffle the edges (maintaining graph isomorphism).

So, if that is what you actually like, see

- [How to efficiently shuffle edges in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610242/how-to-efficiently-shuffle-edges-in-a-graph/40621178#40621178)

If really, you want to control the traversal order of internal library facilities like when using `boost::vertices` then you need a [custom vertex container by defining your own container generator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#SECTION00834100000000000000). An example can be found here, but you'd stand to make substantial modifications to the graph model to get the behaviour you want and I doubt you what get significant benefits (hence my opening statement).

Comment: I find the second approach (but unfeasible as you mentioned) more concise and readable, use less lines of code and based on a reliable library as std <algorithm>